# How to loop find dialog box in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I apologize if my question might seem a bit basic, my coding skills are non existing. As stated above I'm facing a challenge with trying to get the loop dialog box to repeat while performing an action. What I want to do is create a macro were it opens up the find dialog box, lets me enter a number then it will find it and select the whole row and highlight it yellow and repeat until the "ESC" key is pressed. My questions are:

1) When I click the macro it opens the find dialog box were I input my number and press enter, it goes to it but it doesn't continue with the rest until I close the dialog box first and press the macro again. Is there a way to let it close automatically after i enter the number so that it can continue with the rest of the code without me having to press "ESC" to close it and press the macro again?

2) If possible can I make it loop without me having to press the macro more than once to start it off and how?

3) for the life of me I cant seem to find a command that when the "ESC" key is pressed will end the loop. I found a few that interrupt a long updating process when users press Escape key, but what I'm doing isn't a long updating process.

Code:

```
    Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Z
'
    Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1849).Execute
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    ActiveCell.Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

    End With
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: A useful edit to your question would be to show the code you are using...

Comment: My apologize, done

Comment: I would suggest instead of using the built-in Find dialog, use a custom userform that you create. All it would need is a label, a single text entry box, and two command buttons (vbOk and vbCancel). In this way you don't need to catch the ESC key, just wait until the user clicks Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

use `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaFind).Show` instead of and haveorder to let the macro wait for the dialog to close before going on

just remember you have to click the "Find" dialog button at least once in order to get an occurrence which will be used by `ActiveCell` reference in the following macro:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Z
'
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim f As Range, cellsToColor As Range

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaFind).Show
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Set f = .Find(what:=ActiveCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = f.Address
            Do
                If cellsToColor Is Nothing Then
                    Set cellsToColor = f
                Else
                    Set cellsToColor = Union(f, cellsToColor)
                End If
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress

            With cellsToColor.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did that but the problem of still having the dialog box not close after input is still there not to mention i still have to manually click in the box if i want to change the number while also if i don't close the box the effects don't take place, thank you very much though i really appreciate the time and effort you took to do this and i wish you all the best. i took what peterT told me and was able to make the code that i wanted without needing to use "esc" key.

Comment: I don't understand. If you click the "Find Next" button and then close (or Esc) the dialog, it _has_ to work properly